# Prove $(1/(a_{23}+a_{32}),1/(a_{13}+a_{31}),1/(a_{12}+a_{21}))$ is an eigenvector of $A \in SO(3)$ to the eigenvalues one

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Prove $$\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{a_{23}+a_{32}}\\\frac1{a_{13}+a_{31}}\\\frac1{a_{12}+a_{21}}\end{bmatrix}$$ is an eigenvector of $A \in SO(3)$ to the eigenvalue one if the eigenvector even exists in the first place.

The only approach that I've found is the use the property $\det(A)=1$ and $A A^{T}=I$ figure out equations systems for $a_{ij}$ and use these in order to show algebraically $Av=v$. But I know from practical experience that this will take a long time and gets also really ugly.

Comment: what if the coefficients are zero? for example in the case of the unit matrix,

Comment: edited additional condition

Comment: Where is your problem when showing $Av=v$? I think this shoud answer the problem.

Comment: If you look at the formula for [the matrix representing a rotation about the vector $(q_i,q_j,q_k)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Quaternion-derived_rotation_matrix) you see that whenever $n\neq m$ we have $a_{mn}+a_{nm}=K q_nq_m$ for a constant $K$ that depends on the angle of rotation and $q_i^2+q_j^2+q_k^2$. Assuming, as you must, that $q_i,q_j,q_k$ are all non-zero, the claim follows from this. Probably there is a sleek way of showing this also.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen take $q_1q_2q_3$ out, and the alleged eigenvector turns out to be proportional to $q$ which is the axis, hence invariant by rotation.

Comment: Indeed, @Hussein. You are welcome to post the details as an answer.

Comment: I think the recipe works, iff all the coordinates of the axis are non-zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is a rotation matrix, then the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda = 1$ is along the axis of rotation.

Now, on the other hand, a rotation matrix can be decomposed using the Rodrigues' rotation matrix formula as follows

$A = {a a}^T + (I - {aa}^T ) \cos \theta + S_a \sin \theta $

where $a= [a_x, a_y, a_z]^T $ is the unit vector along the axis of rotation, $\theta $ is the angle of rotation, and the skew symmetric matrix $S_a$ is given by

$S_a = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && - a_z && a_y \\ a_z && 0 && - a_x \\ - a_y && a_x && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

From this, and noting the pattern on the off-diagonal elements of the rotation matrix $A$ we find that

$ A_{12} + A_{21} = 2 (a_x a_y) (1 - \cos \theta)$

$ A_{13} + A_{31} = 2 (a_x a_z) (1 - \cos \theta)$

$ A_{23} + A_{32} = 2 (a_y a_z) ( 1 - \cos \theta)$

So, assuming $ \cos \theta \ne 1 $ i.e. $\theta \ne 0 $, then we can write the above as

$ a_z(A_{12} + A_{21}) = 2 (a_x a_y a_z) (1 - \cos \theta)$

$ a_y( A_{13} + A_{31} ) = 2 (a_x a_y a_z) (1 - \cos \theta)$

$ a_x(A_{23} + A_{32} ) = 2 (a_x a_y a_z) ( 1 - \cos \theta)$

Define $K = 2 (a_x a_y a_z) (1 - \cos \theta) $

Then

$a_x = \dfrac{K}{A_{23} + A_{32}} $

$a_y = \dfrac{K}{A_{13} + A_{31} } $

$a_z = \dfrac{K}{A_{12} + A_{21} } $

Therefore, the vector

$\left( \dfrac{1}{A_{23} + A_{32}} ,
 \dfrac{1}{A_{13} + A_{31} } ,\dfrac{1}{A_{12} + A_{21} } \right) = \dfrac{1}{K} (a_x, a_y, a_z) $

is along the axis unit vector $(a_x, a_y, a_z)$ and is therefore an eigenvector of the rotation matrix $A$ corresponding to $\lambda = 1 $.

Comment: I did exclude the case where $\theta =0$ which corresponds to the case where $A=I$

Comment: The solution will work as long as the vector in question is well defined.

Comment: I think this is ok

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, upvoting it, and awarding me the 100 points bounty.  I appreciate that.

Comment: this is selfevident for providing the anwser to an important questoin that has been bothering me for a long time